# tidyverse alternative to bracketed which() matching

Tags: r, matching

I think I'm having a brain fart here. Is there a tidyverse method or other function to return a single value based on the value in another column? I.e., with an example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(c("a", "b"),3), y = 1:6)
> print(df)
  x y
1 a 1
2 b 2
3 a 3
4 b 4
5 a 5
6 b 6
```

Is there a less wordy, hopefully bracket-free function to return `x` given `y`? E.g.,

```
> df$x[which(df$y == 4)]
[1] "b"
```

Comment: try `df %>% filter(y == 4) %>% pull(x)` .

Comment: Generally speaking tidyverse versions of things are more wordy than their base R counterparts (for better or worse)

Comment: You also don't need the `which()` function above, this would work `df$x[df$y == 4]
` or you can do this as well `filter(df, y==4)$x`

Comment: Even with base you can use `subset(df, y==4)$x` .

Comment: @Mike and G. Grothendieck, I think your comments best streamline the answer. If either of you would like to submit as an answer, I can accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible ways to subset a column based on another columns value:

base R:

`df$x[df$y == 4]`

or you can do this as well

dplyr:

`filter(df, y==4)$x`

Answer (score 2):

With `{dbplyr}` trom `tidyverse`

```r
df <- data.frame(x = rep(c("a", "b"),3), y = 1:6)
df |>
  dplyr::filter(y == 4) |>
  dplyr::select(x)
#>   x
#> 1 b
```

Without:

```
df |>
  subset(y==4) |>
  subset(select = x)
#>   x
#> 4 b
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `subset(df, y==4, select = x)`. no need for the 2 subsets. ie `df|>subset(y==4, select=x)`. Nice solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try named vector, e.g.,

```
> with(df, setNames(x, y)[as.character(4)])
  4
"b"
```